# MS SQL on insert to MongoDB

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I'm using MS SQL database which is filling fast, for now I need to keep the MS SQL database, but all the data who is in (one table) I need it to move it to MongoDB.

So it should do it this way...

After insert happens in MS SQL table, it should automatically move the data to MongoDB.
By that I mean the inserted row should automatically be inserted to MongoDB, something like backup.

Any guidelines? Thank you.

Comment: Please explain why negative vote...

Comment: My guess is because it looks like you haven't done any research, and your question is quite vague.

Answer (score 1):

are you expecting that you just install mongoDB and somehow you hook it up with MS-SQL and all your inserts that goes to MS-SQL also ends up in MongoDB ?

well, i am afraid. that wont work.

when you "***After insert happens in MS SQL table, it should automatically move the data to MongoDB***" you have to do some coding to achieve that automation.

1. write scripts to backup MS-SQL,
2. format the backup to proper json,
3. create scripts to import the backed up json data from MS-SQL into mongoDB.